# Is there a reason Yato couldn't summon Nora in the final battle of the first season of Noragami?

Tags: noragami

Nora (a.k.a. Furuhime) retains the mark of her past masters who never officially set her free, so shouldn't she still have Yato's mark on her body, allowing him to summon her at any moment?

If he can, is there any good in-universe reason that he didn't summon her during the final battle (in episode 11) in order to disarm Rabo?  Couldn't Yato have summoned Nora, dropped her onto the ground, and then used Sekki (Yukine) to deal with a weaponless Rabo?

Bishamon is able to have multiple shinki summoned into their non-human form at once, so there is no restriction that you can only have 1 shinki in weapon form at a time.

I assume that once she has been summoned by a god, she cannot be summoned by another god.

Also, while she was in her human form in episode 11, up until Rabo summoned her into his weapon version of her (Reiki), Yato could just as easily have summoned her into his weapon version of her, and if he had done so, Rabo could no longer summon her.

Is this a plot hole: that Yato just didn't think of disarming his opponent when he easily could have done so?

Comment: Given that Yato was effected by Yukine's darkness, master/weapon links aren't a one-way street.  The dialogues about Nora imply that taking her up again would do something to Yato - just the act of accepting her would be a problem, even if he didn't use her to fight.

Comment: True, but 1) by that point in the series shouldn't he be able to manage to hold her for just a second or two without necessarily having to succumb to her darkness (she'd barely have time to even comprehend what he'd done, then to react to it and try to influence him before he could just drop her, and he did successfully undergo Yukine's infection for quite a while before it really overcame him), and 2) even if he couldn't resist the temptation for even a second, I'd think he'd be willing to risk permanent harm to himself if it meant more likely being able to save Hiyori from getting murdered.

Comment: Would you say that the implication is that if Yato picked up Nora for even a split second, not only would he receive damage, but he would necessarily turn back into a magatsukami (god of calamity) and be unable to control himself, ending up killing a lot of people, so for the sake of others he couldn't do it? Even if that meant he, Yukine, and Hiyori would all likely get killed by Rabo and then Rabo would be totally free to roam around killing others? As in, Yato would be a worse magatsukami than Rabo is, so it's better to get killed and let Rabo go wild, than to become a magatsukami himself?

Comment: I think he's worried he might be started down that path again, yes.  And that he wouldn't stop with Rabo, but might immediately go for Hiyori.  But I don't know enough of what makes that setting tick...

Comment: I'd select this if you want to make it an answer

Answer (score 3):

The whole cause of the battle was that Nora wanted Yato to use her again and be the god of calamity; he refused to go back to those times and that led to Nora kidnapping Hiyori.

Even if it would disarm his opponent, it would make him a hypocrite because he wanted to prove that he was no longer a god of calamity.